# ClassCastException whilst using EHCache from shared classloader

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache

I'm trying to setup an EHCache that will be used across various WAR files running on the same Tomcat instance.

The objects I am caching are custom java beans. I am using EHCache version 2.8.3

Ideally, I'd like to do this with only the ehcache JAR being shared at the Tomcat common classloader, from what I have read this should be possible.

The test I am doing has two web services, ServiceA and ServiceB, they are using the same cache as the EHCache JAR is at the Tomcat common lib folder.

When I make a request with ServiceA, the resulting object is successfully inserted in to the cache.

When I make the same request with ServiceB, the resulting object is successfully retrieved from the cache.

However, when I then go back to ServiceA and make the request, it throws a ClassCastException

```
<faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
 <faultstring>com.company.platform.auth.user.AuthenticatedUser cannot be cast to com.company.platform.auth.user.AuthenticatedUser</faultstring>
```

The EHCache Documentation suggests I should set the copyOnRead property to true to ensure the cache will always use serialization. However, adding this in does not seem to have worked for me

http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/enterprise-ehcache/configuration-guide#copy-on-read

Cache Configuration:

```
<cache name="myCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="2000"
       copyOnRead="true"
       copyOnWrite="true"
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off"
/>
```

Cache data is managed using the Spring @Cacheable annotation on the method:

```
@Cacheable(
        value=CACHE_NAME, 
        key="#username + ':' + T(com.company.platform.auth.handlers.EncryptionHandler).encrypt(#password)",
        unless="#result == null")
public AuthenticatedUser authenticate(String username, String password) {
```

Comment: Hello, this should work as expected. Can you add a stack trace of the exception you are seeing and snippets of code around putting and getting from the cache?

Comment: @LouisJacomet Currently I fixed it by handling the serialization myself before sending to the cache. However, this is not the ideal solution it would be better if ehcache could handle that it self. I don't have the exception but there wasn't much to it, it was failing on a $Proxy class and showed no detail in the stack. However, I will add how I am interacting with the cache (it is via spring `@Cacheable` annotation)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Ehcache.

Refernce : https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-976

It was fixed in version 2.6.2

Comment: I'm using version 2.8.3, Ill try the workaround suggested on that page anyway